# MySQL - Where IN together with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sql, mysql

The query used inside the IN() returns:  `1, 2`. However the whole query returns 0 rows which is impossible since they are present. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  li.auto_id
FROM 
  links AS li
  JOIN group_data AS gi ON 
    li.auto_id = gi.autoid AND li.user_id = gi.userid
WHERE 
  gi.groupid IN 
  (
    SELECT 
      CAST( GROUP_CONCAT( gf.groupid ) AS CHAR )
    FROM 
      group_followers AS gf
    WHERE 
      gf.userid_ext = '1'
    GROUP BY 
      gf.userid_ext
  )
  AND li.keyword LIKE '%shiba%'
```

Thank you so much,

Ice

Comment: Ice has asked numerous questions on SO but hasn't Accepted any answer to any of his questions.

Answer (score 8):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> GROUP_CONCAT(expr): 
> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.

You get a *string* containing `'1,2'`. That is nothing you can feed to the IN clause, because it is a *single* value, not two.

Just do it without the `GROUP_CONCAT` and it will work:

```
gi.groupid IN 
(
  SELECT 
    gf.groupid
  FROM 
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel so silly, spent 3 hours figuring out the CAST AS CHAR part and I don't even need the whole GROUP_CONCAT. Good lesson learned, won't ever happen to me again.

Comment: Its perfect and save me to do extra work on these. :)